# Update JSON object from another on specific matching key

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have two json objects, and I would like to extend one to include a value from another, if a specific key matches between the two.

I have accomplished it via this:

```
import json

data = json.loads('{"docs": [{"type": "D", "status": "P", "payment": "P", "value": 176843, "baseId": "0112200196032", "declId": 305724174}, {"type": "D", "status": "P", "payment": "P", "value": 17843, "baseId": "0112190348102"}]}')
comps = json.loads('{"docs": [{"date": "2018-02-14", "baseId": 112200196032, "declId": 305724174}, {"date": "2017-11-13", "baseId": 112190348102, "declId": 299361504}, {"date": "2017-08-05", "baseId": 112178876161, "declId": 293267255}]}')

for dec in data['docs']:
    for com in comps['docs']:
        if int(dec['baseId']) == int(com['baseId']):
            dec['declId'] = com['declId']
print(data)
```

Outputs:

```
   {  
   'docs':[  
      {  
         'type':'D',
         'status':'P',
         'payment':'P',
         'value':176843,
         'baseId':'0112200196032',
         'declId':305724174
      },
      {  
         'type':'D',
         'status':'P',
         'payment':'P',
         'value':17843,
         'baseId':'0112190348102',
         'declId':299361504
      }
   ]
}
```

Do I really need to use a nested for loop? Can it be done more efficiently? List/Dict comprehension?

Comment: Is each item in the `docs` lists guaranteed to have a `baseId`, and is that `baseId` guaranteed to be unique within its scope (i.e. there are no two items in `data["docs"]` or two items in `comps["docs"]` with the same `baseId`)?

Comment: @glibdud yes, order may change though.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of many exception handling that should be done here, your code is actually very readable and considered as a good way to solve this problem. But, if you want to optimize your code you should specify your real optimization scope that whether it is memory optimization of run-time. If the problem is run time you can create a dictionary from `comps` in a format that keys are values of `baseId` and values are the whole dictionary then you can simply do:

```
for dec in data['docs']:
    try:
        val = comps[dec['baseId']]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
        dec['declId'] = val['declId']
```